# How to create a connection string outside web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-config

Just thinking about this, is it possible to create a connection string outside the ASP.NET's web.config?

Comment: Yeah? It's just a string you can store it in a text file, in another database, in the registry... heck you could probably hide it indefinitely in memory somewhere if you were clever enough.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this?

Comment: You can define connectionstring as variable for example  String Connecting ="your connection string" Then call SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(connectiong) etc

Answer (score 3):

Possibly you're looking for [configSource](http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2007/06/07/tip-put-connection-strings-in-their-own-configuration-file.aspx)?

Comment: The link no longer seems to work, but I think this is the same page on the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20080315052221/http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2007/06/07/tip-put-connection-strings-in-their-own-configuration-file.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can store it anywhere it is just text.... The web.config is just a XML document that stores configuration settings about your application. You could just as easily create another XML file or a text file and read it in from there. You just wouldnt be able to use:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[].ConnectionString
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a connection string through the usage of .udl file.

UDL File Creation :

1. Right-click on the desktop, or in the folder where you want to create the file.
2. Select New, then Text Document.
3. Give the Text Document any name with a .udl extension ("Show file extensions" must be enabled in folder options).
4. A window will pop up warning that "If you change a filename extension, the file may become unusable. Are you sure you want to change it?" Select Yes.
5. You have now successfully created a UDL file.

Now you need to implement the settings inside the .udl file according to your requirements. A video tutorial has been provided to explain you the whole procedure of using .udl file to create a connection string for MS SQL Server.

http://visiontechno.net/studymats/udlcreation.html

Answer (score 0):

You can have it in another .config file that gets pulled in by your web.config like this:

```
<appSettings file="../Support/config/WebEnvironment.config">
</appSettings>
```

You can then use it in your code like this:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultConnection"]
```

We have it such that this file isn't physically under our site, but it is virtually under it.  That is the "Support" directory above is a virtual directory. Details can be found [HERE.](http://blog.digitaltools.com/post/2009/06/18/Another-Place-to-Put-the-Connection-String.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following in case of MSSQL server

```
string connectionString = "Your Connection string"  

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    //
    // Open the SqlConnection.
    //
    con.Open();
    //
    // The following code uses an SqlCommand based on the SqlConnection.
    //
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Dogs1", con))
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",
        reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2));
    }
    }
}
```